# What is the correct way of using mixed_precision with tensorflow-rocm?

Tags: tensorflow, amd-rocm

From what I can read, mixed precision has been supported for a long time by rocm and in the TensorFlow-rocm upstream package.  However, when I try to use it, tf still reports compatibility issues:

`Mixed precision compatibility check (mixed_float16): WARNING`

because there is no output from the function tf.config.experimental.get_device_details().  Mixed precision is implemented as follows:  tf.keras.mixed_precision.set_global_policy("mixed_float16") after ignoring the warnings that this is not a NVidia GPU.

Since this has been supported for so long, I wonder if there is something wrong with this approach.  If it has been supported so long, why does it not provide any GPU details, for example?